# Ignore AWS ruby SDK global config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-ruby

I'm working with the AWS ruby SDK and trying to override the global config for a specific client.

When I load the application I set the global config for S3 use like this

```
Aws.config.update(
  endpoint: '****',
  access_key_id: '****',
  secret_access_key: '****',
  force_path_style: '*****',
  region: '****'
)
```

At some point in the application I want to use a different AWS SDK and make those calls using a different set of config options. I create a client like this

```
client = Aws::SQS::Client.new(
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(
    '****',
    '****'
  ),
  region: '****'
)
```

When I make a call using this new client I get errors because it uses the new config options as well as the ones defined in the global config. For example, I get an error for having `force_path_style` set because SQS doesn't allow that config option.

Is there a way to override all the global config options for a specific call?

Comment: I am not using AWS SDK directly. Yet I would suggest to not use a default config. You can then add `force_path_style` only when required (S3 I guess)

Comment: That would work but I'm using an open source project and making that change would require quite a few changes on my end which I want to try to avoid. I was hoping there would be a way that AWS built in to just override the global config options but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Aws.config` supports [nested service-specific options](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/cca0ef069b22e649515e007b0db2f692d6a683ea/gems/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/global_configuration.rb), so you can set global options specifically for S3 without affecting other service clients (like SQS).

This means you could change your global config to nest `force_path_style` under a new `s3` hash, like this:

```rb
Aws.config.update(
  endpoint: '****',
  access_key_id: '****',
  secret_access_key: '****',
  s3: {force_path_style: '*****'},
  region: '****'
)
```

Comment: Awesome, this works great. It allows me to make minimal changes to the open source project for now. Thanks!